# Trying to load a nib from interface builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib, initwithcoder

I have a `UIView` based class that has its own XIB. Lets call this class `MyClass`. So I have `MyClass.xib`, `MyClass.h` and `MyClass.m`.

I have a UIView object on storyboard and I set that object's class to `MyClass`.

I created a new `UIView` XIB and inside the XIB, I changed the File Owner's class to `MyClass`. I don't know if I have to do more connections inside the XIB.

What I want is this: the storyboard loads `MyClass.m` and that loads `MyClass.xib`, for that reason I have this init code:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
        self.view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

The problem is that this code gets in an infinite loop. I guess the `loadNibNamed` call `initWithCoder:` again and the app crashes.

How do I do that? Why the loop and is there any more connections that have to be made inside the xib?

Comment: I don't remember the correct way to do this right now, but the short story is that `loadNibNamed:` actually calls `initWithCoder:`, so that explains your infinite loop instantly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried all answers but this is the only code that worked, after several trials:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

  if (self.view == nil) {
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    [mainBundle loadNibNamed:@"MonthDayPicker" owner:self options:nil];

    [self addSubview:self.view];
    return self;

  }

  return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

lets  do like below

initiate it on `awakeFromNib` method for example

in `MyClass.m` file

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if(self)
  {
      //set up hear
  }
  return  self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  self =   [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  if(self)
  {

  }
  return self;
}


- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   [super awakeFromNib];
   //set up hear
   NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
   UIView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
  [self addSubview:view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `self.subviews.count == 0` breaks the loop, like this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self && self.subviews.count == 0) {
        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
        self.view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: now it crashes on the `loadNibNamed` line with the message **This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:**

Comment: This implies that you should be using awakeAfterUsingCoder with storyboards.  Try that.  I don't use storyboards though so I can't comment.  http://cocoanuts.mobi/2014/03/26/reusable/

Comment: Try my edit (moving the `return self` and getting rid of the `return nil`)

Comment: I'm out of ideas then, sorry. That code is identical to what I'm using, other than the fact that I don't use storyboards.  Maybe there's something declared incorrectly in your xib?